# How to add a custom text block in shopping cart in magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1

How to add a custom text block in shopping cart in magento 2?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to below file

> app/design/frontend/[VendorName]/[theme]/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/item/default.phtml

if above file not your theme then override in your theme after change

and find this code like :

```
                <?php if ($block->hasProductUrl()):?>
                    <a class="cart-product" href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductUrl() ?>"><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getProductName()) ?></a>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getProductName()) ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

after add your logic

Comment: how to add in custom module

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add the following to your `config.xml` under the `<config>` tag:

```
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <expressdelivery>
                <file>expressdelivery.xml</file>
            </expressdelivery>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

Then you need to create your layout file `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/expressdelivery.xml` with the following content:

```
<?xml version="0.1.0">
<layout version="0.1.0">

    <checkout_cart_index>
         <reference name="checkout.cart">
              <block type="core/template" name="extra_block" template="link/to/your/template" />
         </reference>
    </checkout_cart_index>

</layout>
```

Then in your `app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/template/checkout/cart.phtml` you'll need to add the following code:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_block'); ?>
```

Before this code:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('crosssell') ?>
```

You can refer this links too

> [How to add custom block at the /checkout/cart/ page?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125118/how-to-add-custom-block-at-the-checkout-cart-page)
>
> [How do you add a custom block in checkout/cart page in magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/143798/how-do-you-add-a-custom-block-in-checkout-cart-page-in-magento2)